# How to code the number of guesses you made while making guesses in the guess the number game?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I created a number guessing game. It works well but I need help calculating the number of guesses the user has made. This is HTML and JS code. If the user gets the number in X amount of guesses, I want the game to display "You guessed the number in X amount of guesses! You have Y number of guesses left"

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <!--bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

  <body>
<center>
  <div id=text>
    <h1> High-Low Game! </h1>
<p>Please enter a number between 0 and 10000</p>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg" id="input">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">Enter Number Here.</span>
         </div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-lg" id="number">
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="checkValue()">Guess</button>
<br>
<h2 id='result'>Make a inference!</h2>



  </div>
</center>



    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>



let targetNum;
targetNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
function checkValue(){
  let result = parseInt($(".form-control").val())
  if(result>targetNum){
    $("#result").css("color","red");
    $("#result").text("Very Bad Not Even Close");
  } else if(result < targetNum){
    $("#result").css("color","red");
    $("#result").text("Almost There!");
  } else if(result == targetNum){
    $("#result").css("color","green");
    $("#result").text("Very good at guessing! The number was" + targetNum);
  } else {
    $("#result").text("Please re input with an actual number -_-");
  }
}
if (guessCount > 1) {

      if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
        alert("Winner winner taco dinner!");
        break;
      } else if (userGuess > computerGuess) {
        guessCount--;
        alert("Please guess lower. You have " + guessCount + " guesses remaining.");


      } else {
        guessCount--;
        alert("Please guess higher. You have " + guessCount + " guesses remaining.");
    }

    } else {
      alert("MUh hahahahah you lose!");
      break;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far to count the guesses?

Answer (score 0):

couple of problems with your code.  You don't really need to keep track of the users guesses, rather just keep track of the guesses the user has left.  You need to define that outside your function.  Also, Your collection of if statements is coded incorrectly and also must be placed inside the function.  Let me know if this works for you or if there's something you don't understand

```js
var guessLeft=10;

let targetNum;
targetNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
//console.log(targetNum);
function checkValue(){
  let result = parseInt($(".form-control").val())
  if(result>targetNum){
    $("#result").css("color","red");
    $("#result").text("Very Bad Not Even Close");
  } else if(result < targetNum){
    $("#result").css("color","blue");
    $("#result").text("Almost There!");
  } else if(result == targetNum){
    $("#result").css("color","green");
    $("#result").text("Very good at guessing! The number was" + targetNum);
  } else {
    $("#result").text("Please re input with an actual number -_-");
  }
  
  guessLeft--;
  if (guessLeft >= 0) {

      if (result === targetNum) {
        alert("Winner winner taco dinner!");
        
      }else if (result > targetNum) {
       
        alert("Please guess lower. You have " + guessLeft + " guesses remaining.");


      }else{
       
        alert("Please guess higher. You have " + guessLeft + " guesses remaining.");
      }

    }else{
      alert("MUh hahahahah you lose!");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <!--bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

  <body>
<center>
  <div id=text>
    <h1> High-Low Game! </h1>
<p>Please enter a number between 0 and 10000</p>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg" id="input">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">Enter Number Here.</span>
         </div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-lg" id="number">
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="checkValue()">Guess</button>
<br>
<h2 id='result'>Make a inference!</h2>



  </div>
</center>



    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```